# No aparece plantilla MVC en Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

estoy tratando de crear una aplicación ASP.NET con la plantilla de MVC 5. Sin embargo, cuando trato de elegir la plantilla esta no aparece. 
[image: Solo aparece la opción de empty y web api.]

Cuando uso Visual Studio 2013, sí me da la opción de usar MVC 5.
Ya trate de usar la opción de reparar en el instalador de Visual Studio, así como instalé las extensiones de **Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools** y **Microsoft ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2015**.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que cuando seleccionas un proyecto dentro de los template de `ASP.NET 5` en realidad estas seleccionando `MVC 6`

[Getting started with ASP.NET MVC 6](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc.html)

Para usar `MVC 5` deberias de habilitar la opcion dentro de los template de ASP.NET 4.5

[Missing MVC template in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613505/missing-mvc-template-in-visual-studio-2015)

[How to create an MVC 5 project in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548272/how-to-create-an-mvc-5-project-in-visual-studio-2015)

Para que aparezca el template de `MVC 5` sigue el consejo del link, basicamente desde el instalador del VS2015 remueve la opcion `Web developer tools`

Si despues de quitar las Web developer tools no aparece intanta los comentado aqui

[ASP.NET MVC Projects in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eb8cc76f-c134-4974-91c3-3230ac4a7f23/aspnet-mvc-projects-in-visual-studio-2015-enterprise-edition?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

ejecuta el comando

> devenv /InstallVSTemplates

de esta forma haras que se vuelvan a instalar los template

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya intenté todo lo que me dices, inclusive ya había revisado esas preguntas, pero sigue sin aparecer la opción de MVC 5. Lo cual me parece extraño, ya que si lo hago desde VS 2013, sí está MVC 5.

Comment: pero desmarcaste la opcion "Web developer tools" desde el insalador del VS2015 ?

Comment: Así es amigo, intenté desmarcando y marcando.

Comment: actualice la respuesta, valida que ejecutando el comando que reinstala los template no hace aparecer la opcion

Answer (score 0):

En Visual Studio 2015 usa `ASP.NET 5 Templates` > `Web Application`.

El proyecto puede usar MVC 5!

Te comento que tuve la misma confusiòn, ya que la ayuda indica un template MVC exclusivo

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Comment: Gracias por responder, a cual te refieres? Solo me salen las siguientes opciones  http://i.stack.imgur.com/5V4Qc.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar instalar la última versión de ASP.NET 5 para visual Studio ([Microsoft ASP.NET RC1 Update1](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=627627)). Y antes de instalarlo, asegúrate que tienes instaladas las **Microsoft Web Developer Tools** como dicen [aquí](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html#install-asp-net-5-with-visual-studio)

En Visual Studio 2015, las platillas de proyectos MVC5 y MCV6 se han fusionado en un único Wizard por lo que al instalar esta versión, también creo instala o podría reparar MVC5.

Si esto no te funciona, quizás tengas que aplicar medidas drásticas como desinstalarlo por completo y volverlo a instalar (por intentar hacer una instalación limpia)

Espero que te funcione la primera opción, suerte.

Answer (score 0):

Muchachos los que encontre fue instalar el mvc , buscar en la parte superior el mvc step to step además de fijarse en que version del Net Framework se realizara. suerte
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]